# Spaces eaten up in bibliography after location and before colon

Tags: biblatex

I'm very new LaTeX and currently trying to tweak my bibliography to fulfill my needs. This is what it looks like at the moment:

"Frey, Christel: Erfolgsfaktor Vertrauen : Wege zu einer Vertrauenskultur im Unternehmen. 1. Aufl. Wiesbaden: Gabler, 2011. - isbn: 978-3-8349-2539-8."

What I want is a space after the location (goal is: "... Wiesbaden : Gabler ...").

So far I found the "newbibmacro*{institution+location+date}" in the corresponing bbx-file:

```
\newbibmacro*{institution+location+date}{%
\printlist{location}%
\iflistundef{institution}
{\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
{\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
\printlist{institution}%
\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
\usebibmacro{date}%
\newunit}
```

But wherever I added "\space" or s.th. like that didn't change a thing. But nevertheless I am able to insert characters at the desired location. Only spaces are somehow "eaten up".

I'm not sure what you need, so here's some additional information from my tex-file:

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=trad-plain, citestyle=authoryear-icomp, bibstyle=authortitle, maxcitenames=1, babel=other]{biblatex}
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't do that. It is typographically wrong, and you are not even consistent: sometimes you add a space before the colon, sometimes not, like in "isbn:...".

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately this decision is out of my hands. My university is following Lorenzen with his format for DIN1505 which demands a space between the location and the following colon in the bibliography -.- So i gotta use the solution that "ach" provided here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mafp said, spaces before colons are typographically questionable. But, if you absolutely must, you can get an extra space. You have to use the literal colon `:` and not `\addcolon`, as the latter automatically removes all spaces (since it assumes noone would want an extra space before colon).

As you did not provide an example `.bib` file I provided one here - but you only need the bits that are marked.

For consistency, I also made it so you get a space before the colon preceding your `isbn`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=trad-plain, backend=biber, citestyle=authoryear-icomp, bibstyle=authortitle, maxcitenames=1, babel=other]{biblatex}
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}

\addbibresource{document.bib}

%need to copy from here====> 
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\unspace\ :\space}}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat{isbn}{\mkbibacro{ISBN} :\space #1} %adds space in front of isbn colon
%<====to here into your preamble   


\begin{document}

\cite{hume1739}
textcite: \textcite[111]{hume1739}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```